# ESP8266 Webserver ESP8266WebServer variable html page (not as one const char)

Tags: esp8266, programming, web-server, code-review

The aim is to display a non-static html page depending on some variable condition.

The code I created hast the problem, that the esp8266 is ressetting in the moment I request the page.

```
const char htmlIndexHeader[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <ol>
)=====";

const char htmlIndexProgress1[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
        <li>lorem</li>
)====="; 

const char htmlIndexProgress2[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
        <li>ipsum</li>
)====="; 

const char htmlIndexFooter[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
        </ol>
</body>
</html>
)====="; 

char htmlIndexAll[2000]; 

void handleRoot() 
{
  Serial.println("GET /");

   strcpy(htmlIndexAll, htmlIndexHeader);

   if(var1==true)
   {
     strcat(htmlIndexAll, htmlIndexProgress1);
   }

   if(var2==true)
   {
     strcat(htmlIndexAll, htmlIndexProgress2);
   } 

   strcat(htmlIndexAll, htmlIndexFooter);

  server.send(200, "text/html", htmlIndexAll);
}
```

If I display a static page the esp8266 does not restart at page request.

Comment: try strcpy_P and strcat_P

Comment: @Juraj it is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler can't differentiate the PROGMEM strings from constant strings in SRAM strings. Both are `const char*`. But the PROGMEM string must be handled differently. For that reason _P variants of functions exists.

You should use stcpy_P and strcat_P functions.

Note: On esp8266 some functions of Arduino core use a trick to identify PROGMEM strings by their specific address range.